# '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' >>> Não é um problema de input!

Tags: python

A ideia é criar uma matriz de confunsão.
**yhat_tr** tem uma centena de valores(float), positivos e negativos.
**d_tr** é uma coluna dentro de um arquivo de excel com a mesma quantidade de itens que yhat_tr. Os valores de d_tr estão distribuídos para cada idem, mas com valores 1 e -1.

```
#TP - TruePositive, FP: FalsePositive, TN: TrueNegative, FN: FalseNegative
TP, FP, TN, FN = 0,0,0,0

for i in yhat_tr:
  for a in d_tr:
    if i > 0 and a > 0:
      TP += 1

    elif i > 0 and a < 0:
      FP += 1

    elif i < 0 and a < 0:
      TN += 1

    else:
      FN += 1

print (FP)
```

A tentativa é para cada item da coluna y_hat-tr, caso o valor de yhat_tr seja maior que 0 e também seu valor em d_tr seja maior que 0, ele some 1 no valor de TP. Caso contrário soma nos outras variáveis como a regra acima.

Comment: Tem uma string onde você diz que só tem float...

Comment: SIM!!! Você achou a questão.
o d_tr está trazendo o cabeçalho junto dos dados. Quando substituo ele por outra fonte de dados o código funciona. Obrigado!
Agora só tenho que descobrir como importar sem esta legenda da coluna.

Comment: Então, é o que está dizendo a mensagem de erro, você não pode comparar str com int.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sou novo na área também, mas acho que esse loop for que você utilizou é para lista de strings. Para lista de números eu usaria:

```
n = len(yhat_tr)
m = len(d_tr)

for i in range(n):
    for a in range(m):
        if yhat_tr[i]>0 and d_tr[a]>0:
            TP += 1
```

Comment: quase nunca se usa for com "range" em Python - em geral não é necessário.

Formatação de código e identação também não são opcionais na linguagem.

Comment: Obrigado, mas não deu certo.... Deu outro erro (erro 0), e sempre aparece quando aninho estes dois loops (n e m).